# Adding instance methods in jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating my own jQuery plugin. Here is the code which I have written till now:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.customPlugin.defaults = {
        x: 'test',
        y: 'foo'
    };
    $.fn.customPlugin = function (options) {
        var opt = $.extend({}, $.fn.customPlugin.defaults, options);
        return this.each(function () {
            var current = $(this);
            //I want to add instance methods

        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Next I want to add instance methods in this plugin. Now I have two approaches in my mind to do so

1.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.customPlugin.defaults = {
        x: 'test',
        y: 'foo'
    };
    $.fn.customPlugin = function (options) {
        var opt = $.extend({}, $.fn.customPlugin.defaults, options);
        this.each(function () {
            var current = $(this);
            function method1() {
            //opt will be used here
            }
            function method2() {
                //opt will be used here
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

2.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.customPlugin.defaults = {
        x: 'test',
        y: 'foo'
    };
    $.fn.customPlugin = function (options) {
        var opt = $.extend({}, $.fn.customPlugin.defaults, options);
        this.each(function () {
            var current = $(this);
            $.fn.customPlugin.method1(opt);
            $.fn.customPlugin.method2(opt);
        });
    };
    $.fn.customPlugin.method1(opt)
    {
        //opt will be used here
    };
    $.fn.customPlugin.method2(opt)
    {
        //opt will be used here
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Can you please guide me which approach should I use or if you can suggest me better approach than this?

Comment: How do you intend to use the functions? Do you want users of your plugin to be able to use them, or will they be used solely by your plugin?

Comment: Users will just pass options from outside and I will use these methods internally and perform certain operations on html elements of the page.

Comment: To be more clear if you go to this url http://webcloud.se/log/Building-jQuery-plugins/ . Please look the last block of code there you will see a click method: itemControl.click(function() {

                    var link = $(this);
                    var link ........  I just want to separate the code inside the click to some separate function to make the code like itemControl.click(method1) ; where method1 will contain the code which was inside the click event in that example.

Comment: Don't forget to return `this` for chainability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery discourages the second method as it "clutters up the $.fn namespace", check their [documentation here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Plugin_Methods) for the recommended way

Comment: I just went to http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern and there the author has used  $.fn.hilight.format = function(txt) {
    return '<strong>' + txt + '</strong>';
  }; I got second thought from there

Comment: Not quite. jQuery discourages using these: $.fn.myPlugin $.fn.myPluginDelete, $fn.myPluginAdd, NOT these, which is fine: $.fn.myPlugin $.fn.myPlugin.delete $.fn.myPlugin.add